# Blender geometry nodes rotation & reflection

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm in need of creating a set up that has instances aligned along a spiral but are reflecting a central character's position based on the angle they are positioned relative to it.
[image: this is the central character around which the instances are revolving]

This is what the set up looks like currently, all characters are revolved around the character in a radiating fashion/pattern up the spiral.
[image]

Here is the node set up
[image]

What I'd like for is something more like this...
[image]
If it helps, think of it like there is an invisible mirror between each character instance & the character.
I don't know if this is possible but I hope there's a guru out there that knows some magical tree that can solve this.

[image]

This is the file with what I'm trying to replicate. If there's a way besides geometry nodes, I'm open to suggestions to those too.
[image]

Edit 2:
Hey Markus & Quinellform ,After trying out the solutions you suggested
these are the 2 files I came ups with. Didn't make any major changes to the node set up except to maintain things as before
Here's the result with Markus's suggestion.
[image]

Here's the result from Quinellform's suggestion.
[image]

Markus' seems closer to what I'm going for except with the missing character's at the very tips of the sphere.

Edit 3: As Just an update, (sorry I've been a bit busy.)
Both solutions work now. I've upvoted quenellform's solution because the node set up is simpler. But in truth, both @quenellform's & @Markus' solutions working fine. Thanks for your help! I owe you :-)!

Comment: You can share your blend-file at https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Quellenform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now if I understand correctly, you just want all objects mirrored and instantiated around a center, right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Have I mentioned it already? ...I love simple solutions!

1. Subtract the positions of the spiral from the position of the object in the center. This will give you a direction vector pointing away from the center.
2. Then reflect the vector pointing backwards from the center object (in this case $0, -1, 0$) on this direction vector. This will give you a mirrored direction.
3. Then rotate the local Y-axis in the direction of this vector. With this you have your final rotation.
4. So that the object is also instantiated mirror-inverted, you use the node `Transform` there and with it all instantiated objects should be arranged spirally and mirrored around the center.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Quellenform, I used the node tree you suggested & It worked, albeit it's less dynamic than I expected. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seemed it's reliant on a fixed number of instances. Though I wouldn't really mind that. My question really was if it's possible to have the instances reflect the character around the sphere spiral. The method i used from @Markus worked but requires realizing the instances to achieve that. I'll keep trying but it's likely you'll come to a solution before me. 

I'll add some image to show where I am at right now.

Comment: Hello @quellenform,
You asked "Now if I understand correctly, you just want all objects mirrored and instantiated around a center, right?"

In a way yes, but not mirrored around the center more like they should be mirror reflections of a central objects. Think of it like there's a reflective dome around the central object & each face of this dome reflects the side of this object that is "visible to it"

The second set up you made captures it quite close.

Comment: @Phill_R_O OK, Then I would suggest that you think again exactly how it would look if you surrounded the character with reflective surfaces. This solution does exactly that. ;-) Or how do you think it would look if you looked at yourself in a mirror on the floor or ceiling? Or maybe I still don't get it and your questioning is just too confusing for me. ...

Comment: Honestly, I'd say your results look better than mine, and whatever you got wrong, I got right by an accident. I'm afraid I might have been recreating the Reflect node, never used it (just like I use normalize + dot product + multiply and only recently decided to test around and see I'm recreating Project: https://i.imgur.com/gXjdK7A.png) BTW what's with the shadows in your animation? Something suspic about it.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Wow, i have never tried to recreate the reflect-node, amazing! "what's with the shadows in your animation?" This has only to do with the stupid 2MB limit and the color reduction to 12 colors :-)

Comment: @quellenform just to be clear, I linked recreation of Project, not Reflect node, but I don't think recreating Reflect is hard... About the shadows, I understand now, you posterize to reduce the filesize, though I would expect the shadow to still "slide in" rather than suddenly appear on the entire surface - so it looks like the posterization algorithm is region aware? I'm into this kind of stuff so I'd appreciate if you shared the method of how the animation was rendered and post-processed. Cheers!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ...I created the stupid GIF in Photoshop from beautifully rendered single frames. Can you do that directly from Blender? How do you do it?

Comment: @quellenform I often use Photoshop too, just the effect is not something I would expect from Photoshop's posterization options (you exported as legacy GIF?) with dithering or not. And if you want an easier worfklow, you can just export an image sequence, then drag those files to a tool like this: http://apngasm.sourceforge.net/ - and if I really need a GIF, then I just convert it online https://ezgif.com/apng-to-gif , just remember the smallest delay for GIF is `0.02` or `1/50`, lower than that and the GIF actually becomes slower.

Comment: Wow,you guys kept the discussion alive. Super cool! 
@quellenform, yes, you are right. What you did works. Sory I've been busy. But the solution you posted in the blend file does exactly that. So no, i don't think my question is confusing, you nailed it right on the head.
Just so you know, I'm a noob at this, so there's really no way I could have guessed some of the solutions you came up with.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a side note, are there any resources any of you would recommend to help me get the gist of this? or does it come down to practice?

Answer (score 5):

Similarly to Quellenform's answer...

[image]

[image]

### 3D

(third try) [image]

I'm pretty sure it can be done without realizing instances, but I'm lazy as it's getting late...

[image]

[image]

For simplicity (also to make it simpler for myself), I removed the dependency on the Object's Location - I think it didn't work in the first version anyway. But it shouldn't be hard to make it work if need be.

### 3D instances update

Got close to it yesterday, it all comes down to realizing due to Euler XYZ order you need to rotate around Z first. A switch is there to show both approaches result in exactly the same effect, just the bottom doesn't realize instances. This means the bug mentioned in the comments is still there...

[image]

[image]

### 3D bug fix

The bug was very simple, somewhere along the way I accidentally removed *Vector Multiply* × 1; 1; 0. The idea with the setup around Arctan2 (the part that repeats for both solutions) is to take an angle between a horizontal line towards the Z axis, and the height (vertical line to the XY plane, the Z component of the position). So of course without removing the Z component on the first input of the arctan it can't work properly...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Markus von Broady. Yes, you are right. This would definitely be less cumbersome on the computer without realising the instances. But other than that,it works great, even with the spherical spiral. Only difference I noticed was that unlike in the initial example I I can't seem to get the instances at the very tips of the the spirals. I thought it had something to do with the spiral point count. But increasing that had no effect.

Any idea how i should do this?

Comment: @Phill_R_O I fixed both problems. :)

Comment: This works without realizing the instances so that's quite a savior. @Markus von Broady ,thanks!
By the way, I managed to get the objects to flip at the top & bottom of the sphere curve using the map range node. Not sure it's the best solution but it works for now.